# You cannot use a route without an url generator

Tags: symfony, hateoas, representation

i'm trying to implement the Hateoas with PaginatedRepresentation, like describe in documentation :

see bellow my controller :

```
$hateoas = HateoasBuilder::create()->build();
        $paginatedCollection = new PaginatedRepresentation(
            $collection,
            $this->generateUrl('getUsers'), // route
            array(), // route parameters
            1,       // page number
            2,      // limit
            11       // total pages
        );


        return new Response($hateoas->serialize($paginatedCollection, 'json'),
            200,
            array('Content-Type' => 'application/json'));
```

but i got this error : You cannot use a route without an url generator

Comment: error : You cannot use a route without an url generator.

Comment: Please be clear on which bundle you are using and the remaining relevant code!

Comment: I solved the problem, I replaced " $hateoas->serialize($paginatedCollection, 'json') " by  " $this->get('serializer')->serialize($paginatedCollection, 'json') "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replaced :

```
$hateoas->serialize($paginatedCollection, 'json')
```

by

```
$this->get('serializer')->serialize($paginatedCollection, 'json')
```